# Java - Scheduling algorithms for multiple servers

Tags: java, job-scheduling

I'm a university student and I have an assignment, to create a simple scheduling simulator. I'm going to create about 4 algorithms and FCFS is the first but here is the problem. I made the algorithm and it's working but for only one server (because of his speedup usually one of the four servers is the best/faster so every task assigns to this one). I can't find out how to "distibute" the tasks/jobs to the other servers in order to have some balance and not only one do the hard work. For example i usually create 4 servers with speedup from 8 to 12, and 20 tasks. All the tasks check for the server with the best completion time, so if the server with ID 2 has 12 speedup he will always be chosen. I'm stuck with the programming part of how to instruct the scheduler to recognize if a task can still be assigned to the best server or to assinged to another. Also I though of assigning the first 4 tasks to each server but then I don't know how to check which server finished his task and how to inform the system in order for the 5th task to assinged. I thought that something has to do with the arrival time of each task but I'm not sure. So inconclusion all I need is to help me rebuild my code so that it works for many servers and not just one, I checked pseudocodes but it's not so helpfull on the programming part, I would appreciate if somebody has ever done this before and can help me with instructions or code sample. If you don't understand something or need more information just ask me.

Thank you in advance!!!

NOTE: The arrival time it's NOT 0, every task arrives at different time, also it's a simulation so I don't use multithreading, just basic programming.

Here is the FCFS code:

```
public static void Fcfs(ArrayList<Tasks> task,ArrayList<Server> server){
    int taskList_size,serverList_size,i,j,bestServer = -1;
    double tmp_burst,tmp_arrival,bestTime,tmpNewBurst;

    taskList_size = task.size();
    serverList_size = server.size();

    //Find the best server and store + sort all new burst times of a task per server
    i = 0;
    while(i < taskList_size){
        System.out.println("\nNumber: "+(i+1)+" Task ID: "+task.get(i).getTaskId());

        tmp_burst = task.get(i).getBurstTime();        
        System.out.printf("Original burst time: %.3f\n",tmp_burst);

        bestTime = 300000000000.00;
        j = 0;
        while(j < serverList_size){
            tmpNewBurst = tmp_burst/server.get(j).getSpeeUp();
            task.get(i).setServerListTime(tmpNewBurst);

            if(tmpNewBurst < bestTime){
                bestTime = tmpNewBurst;
                bestServer = j;
            }
            System.out.printf("Server ID: %d new burst time %.3f\n",j,tmpNewBurst);
            j++;
        }
        task.get(i).setNewBurtTime(bestTime);
        task.get(i).setBestServer(bestServer);

        System.out.printf("Best server ID: %d best time: %.2f\n",bestServer,bestTime);
        i++;
    }
    //sortTaskArray(task);     

    //Calculate average + total waiting time + average/total turn around time
    averageTime(task);
}
```

Waiting time calculation code:

```
public static void taskWaitingTime(ArrayList<Tasks> task){
    int i,taskSize;
    double[] serviceTime;
    double tmpBurst;
    double tmpWaitingTime;
    double tmpArrivalTime;

    taskSize = task.size();
    serviceTime = new double[taskSize];

    serviceTime[0] = 0.0;
    tmpWaitingTime = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < taskSize; i++){
        // Add burst time of previous processes
        tmpBurst = task.get(i-1).getNewBurstTime();
        serviceTime[i] = serviceTime[i-1] + tmpBurst;

        // Find waiting time for current process =
        // sum - at[i]
        tmpArrivalTime = task.get(i).getArrivalTime();
        tmpWaitingTime = serviceTime[i] - tmpArrivalTime;
        task.get(i).setWaitingTime(tmpWaitingTime);

        // If waiting time for a process is in negative
        // that means it is already in the ready queue
        // before CPU becomes idle so its waiting time is 0
        if (tmpWaitingTime < 0)
            task.get(i).setWaitingTime(0);      
    }
}
```

Turn around time calculation code:

```
public static void taskTurnAroundTime(ArrayList<Tasks> task){
    int i,taskSize;
    double tmpBurst,tmpTurnAroundTime,tmpWaitingTime;

    taskSize = task.size();
    for(i = 0;i < taskSize;i++){
        tmpBurst = (double)task.get(i).getNewBurstTime();
        tmpWaitingTime = task.get(i).getWaitingTime();

        tmpTurnAroundTime = tmpBurst + tmpWaitingTime;
        task.get(i).setTurnAroundTime(tmpTurnAroundTime);
    }
}
```

Average time calculation code:

```
public static void averageTime(ArrayList<Tasks> task){

    int size;
    double waiting,turnAround,avwaiting,avturnAround;

    waiting = turnAround = avwaiting = avturnAround = 0;

    size = task.size();

    //Calculate waiting and turn around time for single best server
    taskWaitingTime(task);
    taskTurnAroundTime(task);

    System.out.println("\nTask's time assigned to the best server");
    for(Tasks x:task){    
        System.out.printf("Task ID: %d Arrival time: %.3f Burst time: %.3f New Burst time: %.3f Waiting Time: %.3f "
                + "Turn around time: %.3f"
                +"\n",x.getTaskId(),(double)x.getArrivalTime(),(double)x.getBurstTime(),x.getNewBurstTime(),x.getWaitingTime(),x.getTurnAroundTime());
    }

    System.out.println();

    //Calculate total waiting and turn around time
    for(Tasks x:task){
        waiting = waiting + x.getWaitingTime();
        turnAround = turnAround + x.getTurnAroundTime();
    }
    System.out.printf("Total waiting time: %.2f Total turn around time: %.2f\n",waiting,turnAround);

    avwaiting = waiting/(double)size;
    avturnAround = turnAround/(double)size;
    System.out.printf("Average waiting time: %.2f Average turn around time: %.2f\n",avwaiting,avturnAround);

}
```

Edited:
Task/Job class:

```
public class Tasks{

private int tId;
private double burstTime;
private double newBurstTime;
private double remainingTime;
private double arrivalTime;
private int bestServer;
private int isCompleted;
private double waitingTime;
private double turnAroundTime;
private double completionTime;
private ArrayList<Double> serversTime;

public Tasks(){
    this.tId = 0;
    this.burstTime = 0.000;
    this.newBurstTime = 0.000;
    this.remainingTime = 0.000;
    this.arrivalTime = 0.000;
    this.bestServer = 0;
    this.waitingTime = 0;
    this.turnAroundTime = 0;
    this.isCompleted = 0;
    this.completionTime = 0;
    this.serversTime = new ArrayList<Double>();
}

public Tasks(int tId,double arrivalTime,double burstTime){
    this.tId = tId;
    this.burstTime = burstTime;
    this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    this.serversTime = new ArrayList();
    this.remainingTime = this.burstTime;
}

public void setBurstTime(double x){
    this.burstTime = x;
}

public void setNewBurtTime(double x){
    this.newBurstTime = x;
}

public void setRemainingTime(int x){
    this.remainingTime = x;
}
public void setBestServer(int bestServer){
    this.bestServer = bestServer;
}

public void setServerListTime(double serverTimeExe){
    this.serversTime.add(serverTimeExe);
}

public void setIsCompleted(int compl){
    this.isCompleted = compl;
}

public void setCompletionTime(double completionTime){
    this.completionTime = completionTime;
}

public void setWaitingTime(double waitingTime){
    this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
}

public void setTurnAroundTime(double x){
    this.turnAroundTime = x;
}

public int getTaskId(){
    return this.tId;
}

public double getBurstTime(){
    return this.burstTime;
}

public double getNewBurstTime(){
    return this.newBurstTime;
}

public double getRemainingTime(){
    return this.remainingTime;
}

public double getArrivalTime(){
    return this.arrivalTime;
}

public double getWaitingTime(){
    return this.waitingTime;
}

public double getTurnAroundTime(){
    return this.turnAroundTime;
}

public ArrayList getServerListTime(){
    return this.serversTime;
}

public int getIsCompleted(){
    return this.isCompleted;
}

public double getCompletionTime(){
    return this.completionTime;
}  

public static Comparator<Tasks> TaskArrTime = new Comparator<Tasks>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Tasks x1, Tasks x2){
        return Double.compare((x1.getArrivalTime()),(x2.getArrivalTime()));
    }
};
```

}

Servers class:

```
public class Server {

private int serverID;
private int coreNum;
private int totalWorkTime;
private int availability;
private int currentTaskID;
private int connections;
private double speedUp;
private ArrayList<Tasks> queuedTask;
//private int energyConsumed;

public Server(){
    this.serverID = 0;
    this.coreNum = 4;
    this.connections = 0;
    this.totalWorkTime = 0;
    this.availability = 1;
    this.speedUp = 8.0;
    this.currentTaskID = -1;
    this.queuedTask = new ArrayList<Tasks>();
    //this.energyConsumed = 0;
}

public Server(int serverId,int coreNum,double speedUP){
    this.serverID = serverId;
    this.coreNum = coreNum;
    this.speedUp = speedUP;
    this.availability = 1;
    this.currentTaskID = -1;
}

public void setServerID(int serverID){
    this.serverID = serverID;
}

public void setCoreNum(int coreNum){
    this.coreNum = coreNum;
}

public void setTotalWorkTime(int totalWorkTime){
    this.totalWorkTime = totalWorkTime;
}

public void setAvailability(int avail){
    this.availability= avail; 
}

public void setCurrentTaskID(int curTask){
    this.currentTaskID = curTask;
}

public void setConnections(int x){
    this.connections = x;
}

public void setSpeedUp(){
    this.speedUp -= 1;
}

/*public void setEnergyConsumed(int energyConsumed){
    this.energyConsumed = energyConsumed;
}
*/

public int getServerID(){
    return serverID;
}

public int getCoreNumber(){
    return coreNum;
}

public int getConnections(){
    return connections;
}

public int getTotalWorkTime(){
    return totalWorkTime;
}

public int getAvailability(){
    return availability;
}

public int getCurrentTaskID(){
    return currentTaskID;
}

public double getSpeeUp(){
    return speedUp;
}

public ArrayList<Tasks> getQueuedTasks(){
    return queuedTask;
}
/*public int getEnergyConsumed(){
    return energyConsumed;
}
*/
```

Comment: Ok, you don't use multithreading (why?), but you must use object-oriented approach for this task. First of all define your class of server, task etc then write your task-processing logic inside their methods.

Comment: @Lev I don't use multithreading because my supervisor professor told me that I don't have to, because it's a simulation we don't want to be so precise. Also I'm using object oriented approach but I don't actually process anything inside their methods. I will edit and add my 2 classes in a few minutes so everyone can see.

Comment: @Lev It's edited. I implement most of the logic in the Scheduler's class, this class contains the methods above like waiting time turnaround, FCFS and also methods that initialize the task and server instances. That's why I don't have any methods like these that you suggest in the Tasks and Server classes. The Scheduler class handles everything, even what happenes to the other 2 classes.

Comment: You have to create a queue of tasks. Thereby you can assign first of your item(task) in this queue to the most fast server, second to slower etc. So you can distribute your tasks. Every server must have "busy flag", so your code can determine free servers.

Comment: @Lev yup that's my issue, let's say that I assigned the first 4 tasks in the right server like you suggested, and update the busy flag from 0 to 1, the 5th task supposed to enter the best server(every 4 tasks the next will assigned again to the best and the rest like the previous tasks like a circle). If the flag of the first is still 1 how is it suppose to enter the server? That's my issue, how am I suppose to compute the waiting time turn around time etc and assume that the task is finished in order to change the flag to 0?

Comment: Can't understand how is your algorithm should work... I would see the invocation of Fcfs method... Could you place your project to github?

Comment: @Lev can't upload it to git, I want but can't for obvious reasons. I will try to think again if I miss something

Comment: @Sentinel Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @Progman thank you for the post, although I don't think that it applies 100% here. I explained everything and if I didn't if anyone has a question can let me know, I searched for my problem for over a month and I don't ask for someone to write my work for me, just a hint or example that he may have encountered before. But still thanks, the post helped me understand some things.